# filter map annotations by distance

Tags: ios, ios7, dictionary, xcode5, mkannotation

I need some help with a filter.  How do I implement an algorithm that filters out related map annotations within the radius of user's location, thanks a lot guys! Any feedback is appreciated! Thank you and have a nice day.

My code I have so far:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
CLLocationDistance test = 1000; // set distance
coordinates.latitude = [[row objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];// get user's latitude
coordinates.longitude = [[row objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinates title:titles subtitle:contents image:[row objectForKey:@"image"]]; // specify annotation's detail

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];// adding annotation into the map
[annotation release];
```

Comment: This is tricky ..do you know the distance?? if you do, you can categorize MapAnnotation and create a NSString property using run time objective C api. then later sort the annotation array or whatever you have using this new key. Something along these lines.

Comment: By distance do you mean the desire distance i want it to filter ? if by that Yes, i do, the distance is set by me not user, can you explain more about how to categorize the MapAnnotation ? Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: Just google it dude.. 1) Creating a Property within Category using Runtime Objective C. 2) Sorting an Array using a key. Too much to write here :)

Comment: If you are OK with straight-line distance, search for `CLLocation` and its `distanceFromLocation` method.  Call that method for each annotation you are _about_ to add.  If the distance is less than or equal to your required radius, _then_ add the annotation.  Doesn't sound like you need to add a property or do any sorting here.